# How to put location data(GeoPoint) property for a custom open graph object that inherits place object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Having trouble putting location data for my custom object that inherits place..

I have tried pretty much everything using my android app, Graph API Explorer and Object Browser.

One thing I really don't understand is I can just simply put values for the properties using 'New Object' in 'Object Browser', but when I click on 'confirm' button there is no error message or warning it just make an object without the location data I put in.

Here are what I put

Object Browser > New Object

og:title            a sample place
   place:location      {"latitude":37.26291082,"longitude":127.06280935,"altitude":98}

Did I put the data wrong or is it a bug?
Help me out please!

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/place/#markup I think you need to format it like this:

```
<meta property="place:location:latitude"  content="37.26291082" /> 
<meta property="place:location:longitude" content="127.06280935" />
```